# WPF Binding doesn't work with class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have binding in XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="mark" SelectedIndex="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=marks}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

In C# code i write

```
 DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

Where ViewModel is class

```
 public class ViewModel
{
    ......
    public int[] marks = new int[4] { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Why I have

`"System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'marks' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModel' (HashCode=46545237)'. BindingExpression:Path=marks; DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=46545237); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='mark'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marks` must be property to be bind-able.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        marks = new int[4] { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    }
    ......
    public int[] marks{get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some steps are below.
 1. Make a public class like as ViewModel.
 2. And create a public properties like as public int[] marks and also use get and set.
 3. Then you can create constructor to pass array values.
 4. After this you can binding with combobox using name.